# Mysql count gives me a very bad performance, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: mysql, performance, count

When I want to get the count of a left join SQL, it takes me very very long time,
I cancelled the query after 1 minutes and didn't get the result.

I have two tables.
One is **customer**, it looks like:

----------------customer---------------

```
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `drpc` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  `VIN` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,

  `cph` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,

  //... another 60+ columns here

 `invalid` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

  KEY `index_drpc_cph` (`drpc`,`cph`),

  KEY `index_drpc_vin` (`drpc`,`VIN`),

  KEY `index_drpc_invalid` (`drpc`,`invalid`),

  KEY `index_cph` (`cph`)
```

---

The other is **repair**, and it looks like:

-------------repair----------------

```
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `drpc` int(10) NOT NULL,

  `cph` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  `czbh` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,

  `gdh` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,

  `kdrq` date DEFAULT NULL,

  // ... another 20+ columns here

  `invalid` int(1) DEFAULT '0',

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

  KEY `gmrepair_cph` (`cph`),

  KEY `gmrepair_czbh` (`czbh`),

  KEY `gmrepair_gdh` (`gdh`),

  KEY `gmrepair_drpc_kdrq` (`drpc`,`kdrq`),

  KEY `index_drpc_invalid` (`drpc`,`invalid`),

  KEY `index_drpc_cph` (`drpc`,`cph`)
```

---

Both tables have a field: 'cph'.

The original requirement is: for given **drpc**, get those data **cph** exists in **customer** but not exist in **repair**.

### My sql statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT cph FROM repair b WHERE b.drpc=77) r ON c.cph = r.cph 
WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.cph IS NULL
```

---

Here is the explain result:

[image]

BTW, 
for drpc = 77 in repair table, there are about 20k records;

for drpc = 76 in customer table, there are about 60k records.

And both tables' storage are: InnoDB.

It takes about 3 seconds to execute the sql above.

But, when I want to get the count of the sql above refers to, it takes me very very long time. It cannot finished even in 60 seconds.

I am not sure what the issue is. 
Could you please give me some pointers, thanks a million!

Comment: When you measure the 3 seconds, is that for all the records to return or only for the first records to appear?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it is not all of the records, I am afriad, it just the first 1000 records.

Comment: It may still be taking the short query more than a minute to get all the rows.  The `count(*)` has to wait until all the rows are finished, so the timing comparison is not apples-to-apples.

Comment: Based on your explain you should get rid of that derived table, i.e., get rid of the `left join ( select ... )` section.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to look at the explain for the plans.  It looks like the index on `drpc, cph` should be used for the query.

However, if your base query works, perhaps this will give you better performance.

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT *
      FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT distinct cph
            FROM repair b
            WHERE b.drpc=77
           ) r
           ON c.cph = r.cph 
      WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.cph IS NULL
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

You may be able to force the execution plan by phrasing the query like this:

```
select count(*)
from customer c
where c.drpc = 76 and
      not exists (select 1 from repair r where r.drpc = 77 and r.cph = c.cph);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I tried your sql, but there is no help. I will add the explain to the topic. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited and added the explain result. Hope it is able to help something, thanks in advance!!

Comment: thanks very much for your comments/replies. For now I think I got the tricky. If, for the derived table, I put `SELECT DISTINCT(cph)` instead of `SELECT cph`, I get a much better performance. BTW, `DISTINCT(cph)` returns 18 rows, and 20k+ if without `DISTINCT`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try left outer join instead of left join.

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Customer C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT cph from 
        FROM Repair WHERE drpc = 77)r  ON C.cph = r.cph
WHERE C.drpc = 76 AND R.cph IS NULL
```

Comment: Uh, `left outer join` is a synonym for `left join`.  This cannot make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the query you provide:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT cph FROM repair b WHERE b.drpc=77) r ON c.cph = r.cph 
WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.cph IS NULL
```

Should be the same as a simple left join (this is the count version):

```
select count(*) from customer c
where c.drpc = 76 and c.cph not in (
    select cph from repair where drpc = 77
)
```

Does this second query take too long too?

Comment: yes, the second one is just the slow case for me, it is slow, and the `select count(*) from (my sql here) t` helps nothing too.

Comment: I don't think there is a faster query than the second one... it is just a left join with no subqueries and based on your indexes it should be pretty efficient too.

Comment: The second query is not equivalent to the first.  The condition `r.drpc = 77` turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: @MostyMostacho, Thank you very much! I read your comment again, and I realized that I didn't read it correctly just now. Yes, your 2nd sql is much faster, but, I cannot get my require data by executing the 2nd sql. The reason is: `WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.drpc = 77 AND r.cph IS NULL`, when the r.cph is null, the r.drpc is null too, based on the `LEFT JOIN repair r ON c.cph = r.cph`, we know that, if the cph is null, it means no matched data in repair table, so the r.drpc is null too, then I cannot get data needed.

Comment: @MostyMostacho, (I cannot type too much in single comment). And for sure, I appreciate your 2nd SQL, it is much better than mine, could you help to give me some pointer on how to get the correct data based 2nd SQL? Thanks a million!!

Comment: My requirement is: for a given `drpc`, find out the records that `cph` exists in `customer` table, but not in `repair` table. For example, the given `drpc` for `customer` is 76, and for `repair` is 77, I need to find out the `cph` exists in `customer`'s drpc: 76 and it does not exist in `repair`'s drpc: 77. If the repair's cph is null, it means all of the other columns of `repair` table will be null too, am I right? Thank you!!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Yes, u'r right, the condition `r.drpc=77` make the left outer join to be an `innner join`, that's why I cannot get the wanted data. Thank you!!

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. Ok, I've edited the second query... it won't be quite efficient but should give you the results you're looking for. Give it a try... (I can't think of a solution without a subquery :/)

Comment: @MostyMostacho, Thanks a lot for your reply!! I re-analysed my question, it seems like `DISTINCT(cph)` helps me for now. So the SQL looks like `SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT DISTINCT(cph) FROM repair b WHERE b.drpc=77) r ON c.cph = r.cph 
WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.cph IS NULL `. It takes only 0.3 second. If there is a `distinct`, it returns only 18 rows, and 20k+ without it. That's the key point for now, however, I cannot hold my breath, data in my pc is just sample data rather than real production data. I will do more experiments to make it straight. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why others did not mention, but  the subquery in your query does not allow indexes to be used efficiently, you actually left join on an unindexed table with 20k rows.

For the query you need 2 indexes:
(drpc, cph) on customers and (cph, drpc) on repair (mind the order, you do not have it yet).

Then you need to rewrite the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  customer c
LEFT JOIN repair r ON c.chp = r.chp AND r.drpc = 77
WHERE c.drpc = 76 AND r.chp IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointer! Yes, the subquery is another table without any index. I just wander how to make it indexable. I tried your SQL, it is pretty fast, but, I wasn't able to get the data I want, because, when `r.cph is NULL`, `r.drpc` is NULL too, and there is no something like `77` even after I tried some modifications on your SQL. Could you please give me more pointers how to get the correct data? I do need a effcient SQL to find out those data exist in TableA but not in TableB (for me, there is another restriction, that is `drpc`). Thanks a million in advance!!

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO, I am sorry, `r.drpc = 77` should certainly go into `ON` clause, I will correct my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update!! I will give is a spin and will update you for the result! Thanks again!! Please have a very nice day!!:)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the real trick.

It is because of the left join filed `cph`, which is a `varchar(10)`, that caused the VERY VERY slow when doing left join job.

I create a new column: `hash_cph numberic(30,0)` on both tables and then convert the `cph` to some `MD5` hash numbers in this way:
`UPDATE customer SET hash_cph = CONV(RIGHT(MD5(cph),16),16,10)`.

So I can apply left join on the new created column `hash_cph` now, it will be much much more faster. 
The final SQL looks like:
`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  customer c
LEFT JOIN repair r ON c.`hash_cph`= r.hash_cph AND r.drpc = 32 WHERE c.drpc = 1 
AND r.hash_cph IS NULL;`

btw, I also added index on `drpc and hash_cph` for both tables.

Thanks for everyone's help!!